# IBM Worklight - Regarding terms in Worklight Console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-console

I am creating a worklight application that covers all the featues provided by worklight. In the worklight console, on the right side we get four options namely
1. security test
2. App Authentication
3. Device Authentication
4. User Authentication
What for these options provided for? can we set some other values to them instead of default? If so how? can you please explain sir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You really must read through the [IBM Worklight Information Center](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp).
2. Before you are developing your application, you **MUST** do everything in the [IBM Worklight Getting Started materials](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/library/), if you intend on creating such an application

This place is for technical questions.
What you're asking is not technical.

When you set up your project/application with a security test, app authenticity, device provisioning/authentication or use any authentication, such information will be displayed in the application section in Worklight Console, so depending on how you configure the application, different information will be displayed.

So again, learn Worklight first. See my links at the top.

Comment: Thank you..I have gone through the docs and now I am clear about those terms.